# $\sum e^{(-nx)}\cos(nx)$ is not a uniformly convergent series?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

How   to prove that
$\sum e^{(-nx)} \cos(nx)$ is not a uniformly convergent series?  Where $x$ is a positive real number.

My try: Local Minimums of $e^{(-nx)} \cos(nx)$ attain at x = $3\pi/4n +3m\pi/2n$ and min value will be a fixed negative number for each n. We can not say anything about convergence or divergence from this. Abel's test and Dirichlet's test also fail to decide anything about convergence and divergence..

Comment: What is the domain for $x$?

Comment: positive real number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that your series is uniformly convergent on $I=]0,+\infty[$. This means that the partial sum $S_n(x)$ converge uniformly on $I$, hence $S_{n}(x)-S_{n-1}(x)=\exp(-nx)\cos(nx)$ converge uniformly to $0$. Hence for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exist an $N$ such that for every $x\in I$ and $n\geq N$, we have $\exp(-nx)|cos(nx)|<\varepsilon$. Now take $\varepsilon<e^{-1}|\cos(1)|$, and $x=1/n$.

Comment: Okk..one necessary condition for being a series uniformly convergent is the sequence $|S_n - S_(n-1)|$ will be uniformly convergent to 0...Is not it?@Kelenner

Comment: @cmi Yes, this is the same idea that for numerical series: if you have a series $a_n$ for the convergence of the series, the first thing to verify is that the sequence $a_n\to 0$. For the uniform convergence of series of functions, say $u_n(x)$ , the first thing to verify is that the sequence $u_n(x)$ go uniformly to $0$

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

Step 1:

> We define the partial sum $$S_m(x)=\sum_{n=0}^m e^{-nx}\cos(nx)$$

Step 2:

> $\cos(nx)=1\Leftrightarrow nx=2\pi k$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Step 3:

> Consider $|S_{m}(x)-S_{m-1}(x)|=e^{-mx}|\cos(mx)|$.

Step 4:

> $\sup_{x>0} |S_m(x)-S_{m-1}(x)|\geq \left|S_m\left(\frac{2\pi}{m}\right)-S_{m-1}\left(\frac{2\pi}{m}\right)\right|=e^{-2\pi}|\cos(2\pi)|=e^{-2\pi}$. Therefore $(S_m)_m$ is not convergent uniformly on $(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** first ask yourself what domain are you considering, than use that
$$
\sum_ne^{nx}\cos(nx)=\Re\left(\sum_ne^{nx(1+i)}\right)
$$

Comment: x is a positive real number... I did not get u..Can u plzz elaborate little bit...

Comment: @cmi Look up Euler's formula.