# Find the domain of pointwise convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }e^{-nx}\cos(nx)$ by showing contradiction

Tags: real-analysis, pointwise-convergence

I tried to make a contradiction for this by supposing this series converges on some $k\in \mathbb{R}$.

> Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }e^{-nx}\cos(nx)$ converges to some $f(x)$ pointwisely when $x=k\in
> \mathbb{R}$ for some $k$.   Then this means, it converges to
> $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }e^{-nk}\cos(nk)$
>
> Now, we can observe that

$$\frac{1}{1-e^{k}}=-\sum \frac{1}{e^{nk}}\leq \sum \frac{\cos(nk)}{e^{nk}}\leq \sum \frac{1}{e^{nk}}=\frac{1}{e^{k}-1}$$

> If $k<0$, then $\frac{1}{1-e^{k}}> 0$ and $\frac{1}{e^{k}-1}< 0$. But,
> there doesn't exist $f(k)$ satisfying the condition. Thus, $k>0$.

But, I can't find a method to find a contradiction for $k>0$.

Can I get some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why wouldn't this converge pointwise on the set of positive reals though:

For all $x>0$ note that $$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |e^{-nx} \cos nx| \le \frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}$$ in particular is finite, which implies that the sum
$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} e^{-nx} cos nx$ must converge for each such $x$ as well.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622828/do-these-series-converge-uniformly?noredirect=1&lq=1. The answer here says that it doesn't converge on all real numbers. So, I wanted to prove why this is true. But, it seems like it isn't even true?

Comment: @john The problem is that the linked answer says the series "doesn't even converge pointwise on all $\mathbb R$", which is intended to mean "it's not the case that, for all $x\in\mathbb R$, the series converges", but which you read as "for all $x\in\mathbb R$, it's not the case that the series converges." And those are very different meanings. (English, like most natural languages, can be ambiguous.)

Comment: And yes sometimes there are mistakes in past answers on here too. People here are talented and do their best, but we are still all only human too.